# XAMPP Control Panel mysql shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mariadb, innodb, xampp

When I try to start on mysql from xampp control panel it says:

```
20:52:08  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
20:52:08  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:52:08  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:52:08  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:52:08  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:52:08  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:52:08  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:52:08  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

below is the log file:

```
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 8176
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1156629
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 1157132; transaction id 1865
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-23 20:52:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

please help me on what to do next[image]

Comment: Knowing what happened between "20:52:02" and "20:52:08" would be good. Could it be XAMPP starting a different instance than what the successfully started MariaDB logs are showing? The MariaDB logs are showing an initialization of the datadir which is odd as the XAMPP logs show it attempting to start earlier. Any hints in Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Windows event viewer was telling the port is blocked. So tried changing the ports, it didn't help. Deleted anyother instances of SQL, still nothing. Tried a few more ways told to me on stack overflow, nothing helped. In the end, I deleted and reinstalled XAMPP and it works now. Still don't know what the issue was though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution:

https://buildio.dev/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/

> Navigate to your XAMPP MySQL directory (C:\xampp\mysql).
>
> Create a new folder called DATA_BROKEN and copy C:\xampp\mysql\backup
> and C:\xampp\mysql\data into this folder.
>
> Paste the contents of C:\xampp\mysql\backup into C:\xampp\mysql\data,
> overwriting all the files. Note the dates may be older that your most
> recent activity.
>
> Copy the ibdata1 file from C:\xampp\mysql\DATA_BROKEN \data into
> C:\xampp\mysql\data overwriting the file.
>
> Then start MySQL.